# Access SQS from On-Prem Servers

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs

I am trying to post messages to SQS queue from on-prem servers. When I run it locally , I use AWS secret id and key to post messages to SQS. But this is something that I need to generate every few hours. If I want to deploy this solution to a server and not have to refresh the token every few hours , what is the solution that I must adopt?

Comment: IAM users' static access key and secret key never change unless manually (or via a custom script) updated. You can use these keys for accessing AWS resources from on-prem servers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use any of the AWS SDK'S to build your on-premise application, you give the application the IAM access keys (the access key id and the secret access key), (often these end up in your ~/.aws subdirectory but it might vary for each language) and then each time your on-premise application calls any of the AWS functions the the AWSSDK, the app will provide the necessary keys.

These keys should only be given the bare minimum of rights to do only what you want, for example, in you case, the would have only rights to post messages to a particular SQS queue.